# How to write BCE dates in org-mode

Tags: org-mode, time-date

I need to write BCE dates in org-mode. I'm particular about consistency and it kills me to have to write dates two different ways.

I'm hoping there's something like `[-7000-01-01]` to denote January 1st 7000 BCE. (I'm also wondering if there's a way to only write the year, but that's for a separate question I suppose).

Comment: Did you check the documentation? What does it say?

Comment: There's no mention of BCE dates anywhere. I couldn't find any SO questions or posts on other sites either. I did try to find the answer before posting here.

Comment: So include in your question what the documentation actually says, and what experiments you tried.

Comment: How can I include what the documentation says if the issue is that it doesn't say anything? I don't understand.

Comment: Just paste in a quote from the documentation that shows what the syntax is (I see several good examples). Then note that it doesn’t say anything about calendar eras or negative years. Then show the experiments that you tried in an org-mode file, and what the results were.

Comment: Do `C-h v org-read-date-force-compatible-dates` and read it. By default it is t and Org mode limits any dates it reads using the usual date/time prompts to dates with years 1970-2037. You can set it to nil (at your own risk) and expand that range substantially, but practically speaking Org mode is limited to years 0-9999, because a) negative years are not recognized and b) years with more than four decimal digits are not recognized. Those are limitations of the regexps that are used for fontification of dates: if you step outside the limits, the fontification disappears.

Comment: I suspect (but have not checked) that much of the code doing time calculations probably works with a wider range (roughly 300 billion years if I've done the arithmetic right), but I would not hold my breath. The question is: what exactly do you want to do with such dates?